# Java conversion of func_get_args PHP, varargs

Tags: java, php, variadic-functions

Cordial Greetings...

I hava this in PHP.

```
function Func0($sString1,$iInteger0,$sString2) {
  $OrigArgs = func_get_args();//The arguments
  Func1($OrigArgs,1);
}
function Func1($OriginalArgs,$AddedArg) {
  $NumFirstArgs = size($OriginalArgs);
  if ($NumFirstArgs>3) {
    print("you have more than 3 arguments originally");
  }
}
```

I need to translate the above code to Java

I need in java catch the originally arguments/parameters and to use them in other function...

As you can see the arguments can be with different type according to Java..

```
public void Func0(String sString1,int iInteger0,String sString2) {
  Object[] OrigArgs = func_get_args();//The arguments
  Func1(OrigArgs,1);
}
public void Func1(Object[] OriginalArgs,int AddedArg) {
  int NumFirstArgs = OriginalArgs.length;
  if (NumFirstArgs>3) {
    System.out.println("you have more than 3 arguments originally");
  }
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: Where are you using varargs in your PHP code?

Comment: Yes, but it's rectifiable, As you can see the problem is with func_get_args(), I don't know grouping.
I think in varargs, because can be applicable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Object[] func_get_args(Object... argv) {
  int TheSize = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i<argv.length; i++) {
    if(argv[i]!= null && argv[i].getClass().isArray()) {
      Object[] OneArray = (Object [])argv[i];
      TheSize += OneArray.length;
    } else {
      TheSize += 1;
    }
  }
  Object[] NewArray = new Object[TheSize];
  int ThePos = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i<argv.length; i++) {
    if(argv[i]!= null && argv[i].getClass().isArray()) {
      Object[] OneArray = (Object [])argv[i];
      System.arraycopy(OneArray, 0, NewArray, ThePos, OneArray.length);
      ThePos += OneArray.length;
    } else {
      Object[] OneArray = {argv[i]};
      System.arraycopy(OneArray, 0, NewArray, ThePos, 1);
      ThePos += 1;
    }
  }
  return NewArray;
}
```

Using the new method:

```
  String Name = "AStringExample";
  String Style = "TheStyle";
  Object[] argv = {7,9};
  Object[] argc = {Name,Style};
  Object[] NewArray = func_get_args(argv,Name,Style,argc);
  for (int i = 0; i < NewArray.length;i++) {
    System.out.println("i="+i+" -> "+NewArray[i].toString());
  }
```

The output:

```
i=0 -> 7
i=1 -> 9
i=2 -> AStringExample
i=3 -> TheStyle
i=4 -> AStringExample
i=5 -> TheStyle
```

Using like the question:

```
public void Func0(String sString1,int iInteger0,String sString2) {
  Object[] OrigArgs = func_get_args(sString1,iInteger0,sString2);//The arguments
  Func1(OrigArgs,1);
}
public void Func1(Object[] OriginalArgs,int AddedArg) {
  int NumFirstArgs = OriginalArgs.length;
  if (NumFirstArgs>3) {
    System.out.println("you have more than 3 arguments originally");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a last parameter like `Object... foo`, then `foo` will be an array of all of the varargs, i.e. all of the "rest of" the parameters other than the non-variable arguments. In other words, you could declare your function as

```
public void Func0(String sString1, int iInteger0, String sString2, Object... more)
```

but `more` would only contain the arguments *after the 3rd one*.

To most closely match your original code, you would do (`sString1`, `iInteger0`, and `sString2` are no longer parameters and you would have to extract them manually if you want them):

```
public void Func0(Object... OrigArgs) {
  Func1(OrigArgs,1);
}
public void Func1(Object[] OriginalArgs,int AddedArg) {
  int NumFirstArgs = OriginalArgs.length;
  if (NumFirstArgs>3) {
    System.out.println("you have more than 3 arguments originally");
  }
}
```